# Failed to login: Failed to send request to https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/41.0

Tags: ant

I am having hard time during code retrieve from source org through ANT. I don't have proxy enabled and the username and password+security token is also correct but still I am getting below error

C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\salesforce_ant_41.0\sample\build.xml:34: Failed to login: Failed to send request to https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/41.0

Please help me in resolving this

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68831/discussion-on-question-by-debarun-sengupta-failed-to-login-failed-to-send-reque).

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: Just to verify that it's not a network error, can you do a "curl -v https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/41.0" and check that you get a 405 Method Not Allowed and not another network error?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to check the ant command error, try to execute `ant -verbose` in command. It will show you the error details.

For my cases, I upgraded my JDK and I forgot to import sandbox SSL cert into new JVM, it threw "Failed to login" error whenever I tried to run ant deploy. What I did was - checked the verbose and found out handshake failure, after I imported the cert, it worked.